# vb.net drag and drop swap labels positions

Tags: vb.net

The code below is supposed to allow the user to drag one label onto another causing the locations of the two labels to swap.

```
Dim firstLabel As Label

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label2.AllowDrop = True
End Sub

Private Sub label1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Label1.DoDragDrop(Label1, DragDropEffects.All)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub label2_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles Label2.DragEnter
    firstLabel = Label2
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(Label)) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub label2_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles Label2.DragDrop
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(Label)) Then
        Label2 = CType(sender, Label)
        Label1 = firstLabel
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem I am having is when I drag and drop label1 onto label2 nothing happens.
Another problem leading on from this one is that I need the drag and drop feature to work on more than two labels and I have no idea how to go about making that efficiently.
 Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it mostly right.  In your `DragDrop` event, you are not using the `Label` stored in `e.Data` and the direct references (ie `Label1`) prevent it from working either way (ie L1 to L2 and L2 to L1).

```
Private Sub lbl_MouseMove(sender As Object, 
      e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseMove, Label2.MouseMove

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim lbl As Label = CType(sender, Label)
        ' sender could be Lbl1 or Lbl2 - we dont care
        lbl.DoDragDrop(lbl, DragDropEffects.Move)
    End If

End Sub
```

Since `sender` is the one being dragged, cast it back to label, and set that as the drag data object.  Notice also how the one event is set to handle both labels via the `Handles` clause.  This would also hold for DragEnter:

```
Private Sub Lbl_DragEnter(sender As Object, 
      e As DragEventArgs) Handles Label1.DragEnter, Label2.DragEnter
```

Then, in the `DragDrop` event just swap the `Location` of the 2 labels:

```
' handles DragDrop for both controls (or more)
Private Sub Lbl_DragDrop(sender As Object, 
        e As DragEventArgs) Handles Label1.DragDrop, Label2.DragDrop

    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(Label)) = False Then Exit Sub

    ' sender == Droppee
    Dim lblA As Label = CType(sender, Label)
    ' e.Data == Dragee
    Dim lblB As Label = CType(e.Data.GetData(GetType(Label)), Label)

    Dim pt As Point = lblA.Location

    ' swap locations
    lblA.Location = lblB.Location
    lblB.Location = pt

End Sub
```

`sender` is one label, `e.Data` is the other.  We dont need to know which is which, all that matters is that we want to swap locations.

Comment: hey, thanks for the help. I have a few questions. 1) is there any of my original code that I need to keep (ie the DragEnter event)? 2) The last line of code "lblMouseDown = False" has a declaration error, is this line needed or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, keep the DragEnter code - it was fine as is (except you do not need `firstLabel` at all), so I did not repeat it.   Ignore `lblMouseDown` it was something else I was toying with - I removed from the answer.

Comment: I've come across a problem, when I drag one label over another to swap them, it doesn't allow me to do it. I think the problem is to do with my DragEnter event because the icon shown on the mouse doesn't indicate that I cant drop it there. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I'm mostly using your `DragEnter` code and it works fine.  a) get rid of `FirstLabel` entirely, b) make sure that `DragEnter` like all the DragDrop related events use the compound `Handles...` clause.  c) Make sure your code isnt still using `Label1` or `Label2` somewhere